# a dark transparent mask for div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to apply a dark transparent mask on the product div when someone hovers on the product image. I have created mask for the whole screen before. I used the same logic this time as well, but it acts really weird. I tried to use mouseenter, mouseleave but it doesn't work. The mask just keeps appear then disappear even my mouse pointer did not leave the image. Below is how it looks: and I don't know why the mask target the whole screen when I already target box1 in jquery.

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Vw8b/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="box1">
<img src="http://smilesoftware.com/assets/images/uploads/products/icon_pdfpenipad_140x140.png" alt="orange" title="orange" />   
<a href="#">View Detail</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div#box1 {
  border: #999 2px solid;
  width: 180px;
  height: 250px;
}

div#box1 > img {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2000;
  max-height: 240px;
}

div#box1 >a {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top:100px;
  left: 40px;
  margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
  z-index:3000;
  background: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

div#box1:hover a {
  display:block;
}

#mask {
  display:none;
  background: #000;
  position:fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2500;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.75;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
$('#box1 img').mouseenter(function () {
    $('#box1').append('<div id="mask"></div>');
    $('#mask').fadeIn(400);
});

$('#box1 img').mouseleave(function () {
  $('#mask').fadeOut(400, function () {
    $('#mask').remove();
  });
});
```

If you have any idea what I am doing wrong, your help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: once you hover the mask, you do not hover the image anymore. you should apply CSS as well to mask when hovered . mask could be a pseudo element of #box1 and plain css apply to box1:hover:before {transition:0.4s ; opacity :1;} for instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my comment, using a pseudo element and no jQuery **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5Vw8b/9/)**:

```
div#box1 {
  border: #999 2px solid;
  width: 180px;
  height: 250px;
  position:relative;
  text-align:center;
}
div#box1 > img {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  max-height: 240px;
}
div#box1 >a {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top:100px;
  left: 40px;
  margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
  z-index:3;
  background: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
div#box1:hover a {
  display:block;
}
div#box1:before{    
  content:'';
  background: #000;
  position:absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition:0.4s;
  opacity:0;
}
div#box1:hover:before{  
  opacity:0.75;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I also just used CSS.  Here is my JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/4UNuB/

**HTML**

```
<div id="box1"> 

<a href=""><div id="black-box">
    <h2>View Details</h2>
</div></a>
```

**CSS**

```
    #box1 {
    border: #999 2px solid;
    width: 180px;
    height: 250px;
    background-image: url(http://smilesoftware.com/assets/images/uploads/products/icon_pdfpenipad_140x140.png);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#black-box {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: rgba(00,00,00,0.8);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.0;
}

#black-box:hover {
    opacity: 1.0;
}

h2 {
    padding-top: 110px;
}
```

Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

I did not use any jquery but dsimply used css element to achieve the effect that i think tht you want... here is the fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/5Vw8b/2/ hope this is waht you wanted.

i added..

```
div#box1:hover > #mask{
display:block;
```

in the css and in the html part i added..

```
<div id="box1">
<div id="mask"></div> <!-- this line added -->
<img src="http://smilesoftware.com/assets/images/uploads/products/icon_pdfpenipad_140x140.png" alt="orange" title="orange" />   <a href="#">View Detail</a>
```